# Create OData provider for Excel - Power query shows $metadata xml

Tags: php, excel, odata

I'm creating an OData provider to be used with Excel with a PHP library: https://github.com/Algo-Web/POData

I've managed to deliver a Sample data set in the browser on my local network with:

http://dss.example.com/proto/odata.svc/Samples?$format=json

```
{
  "value":[
    {
      "id":"1","firstName":"Rebbecca","lastName":"Didio","companyName":"Brandt, Jonathan F Esq","address":"171 E 24th St","city":"Leith","state":"TA","post":"7315","phone1":"03-8174-9123","phone2":"0458-665-290","email":"rebbecca.didio@didio.com.au","web":"http://www.brandtjonathanfesq.com.au"
    },{
      "id":"2","firstName":"Stevie","lastName":"Hallo","companyName":"Landrum Temporary Services","address":"22222 Acoma St","city":"Proston","state":"QL","post":"4613","phone1":"07-9997-3366","phone2":"0497-622-620","email":"stevie.hallo@hotmail.com","web":"http://www.landrumtemporaryservices.com.au"
    },{
      "id":"3","firstName":"Mariko","lastName":"Stayer","companyName":"Inabinet, Macre Esq","address":"534 Schoenborn St #51","city":"Hamel","state":"WA","post":"6215","phone1":"08-5558-9019","phone2":"0427-885-282","email":"mariko_stayer@hotmail.com","web":"http://www.inabinetmacreesq.com.au"
    },{
      "id":"4","firstName":"Gerardo","lastName":"Woodka","companyName":"Morris Downing & Sherred","address":"69206 Jackson Ave","city":"Talmalmo","state":"NS","post":"2640","phone1":"02-6044-4682","phone2":"0443-795-912","email":"gerardo_woodka@hotmail.com","web":"http://www.morrisdowningsherred.com.au"
    },{
      "id":"5","firstName":"Mayra","lastName":"Bena","companyName":"Buelt, David L Esq","address":"808 Glen Cove Ave","city":"Lane Cove","state":"NS","post":"1595","phone1":"02-1455-6085","phone2":"0453-666-885","email":"mayra.bena@gmail.com","web":"http://www.bueltdavidlesq.com.au"
    },{
      "id":"6","firstName":"Idella","lastName":"Scotland","companyName":"Artesian Ice & Cold Storage Co","address":"373 Lafayette St","city":"Cartmeticup","state":"WA","post":"6316","phone1":"08-7868-1355","phone2":"0451-966-921","email":"idella@hotmail.com","web":"http://www.artesianicecoldstorageco.com.au"
    },
    ...
}
```

and corresponding metadata on http://dss.example.com/proto/odata.svc/$metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" Version="3.0">
    <edmx:DataServices m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0">
        <Schema Namespace="Proto">
            <EntityType OpenType="false" Abstract="false" Name="Sample">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="firstName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="lastName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="companyName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="address" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="city" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="state" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="post" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="phone1" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="phone2" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="email" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="web" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityContainer Name="Proto" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="Proto" EntityType="Proto.Sample" cg:GetterAccess="Public"/>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Through recording of headers I have confirmed that Excel makes the following requests:

Request 1 for what appears to be all data. The library responds with JSON to this

```
User-Agent: Microsoft.Data.Mashup (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=304225)
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;q=1.0,application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;q=0.9,application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8,application/atom+xml;q=0.8,application/xml;q=0.7,text/plain;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Request 2 just for JSON

```
User-Agent: Microsoft.Data.Mashup (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=304225)
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: ds1.example.com
```

The library responds with JSON to this

Request 3 for atom/xml

Through trial and error I have determined to return the metadata here

```
User-Agent: Microsoft.Data.Mashup (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=304225)
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;q=1.0,application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8,application/atom+xml;q=0.8,application/xml;q=0.7,text/plain;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: ds1.example.com
---Request Start: /proto/odata.svc/Samples---
User-Agent: Microsoft.Data.Mashup (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=304225)
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8,application/atom+xml;q=0.8,application/xml;q=0.7,text/plain;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

However this displays the XML metadata in PowerQuery as the results of the query.

I have also modified my OData backend to return xml as it would when requesting through the browser: http:/dss.example.com/proto/odata.svc/Samples

For this variant Excel shows an error:

> "Odata: The given URL neither points to an OData service or a feed: "

I'm new to OData, the purpose here is to deliver Table data over a web portal without requiring to install anything on the machine running Excel, otherwise I would use ODBC